# How to use WHERE in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying this but getting no success

```
var v=ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable().Where<DataRow>(r=>r.Field<int>("productID")==23);
GridView1.DataSource=v;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

gridview showing only one row heading RowError HasRrror but I am expecting one row with product information.

Comment: What's resulting in the lack of success...an error?

Comment: Unless you provide more information you will get no success here either.

Comment: Well i think you need a `.ToList` at the end as your are assigning it as source

Comment: V4Vendetta sorry same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try using `CopyToDataTable`

```
ds.Table[0].AsEnumerable().Where<DataRow>(r=>r.Field<int>("productID")==23).CopyToDataTable();
```

When you convert it to an Enumerable the filtered list has no identifiers for say `ProductID` hence the grid would fail to map the column and fail.

Alternatively you may also choose to use `AsDataView()` instead of `CopyToDataTable()`.

A more detailed explanation can found [Binding DataRows](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html)

> Databinding is controlled by the ListBindingHelper and TypeDescriptor
>   classes.  When you bind to a list, the
>   ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties method is called to get the
>   columns in the list.  If the list implements the ITypedList interface,
>   its GetItemProperties  method is called.  Otherwise, it will use
>   TypeDescriptor to get the properties of the first item in the list. 
>   (this uses reflection)
>
> The DataView class (which DataTable also binds through, using
>   IListSource) implements ITypedList and returns
>   DataColumnPropertyDescriptors that expose the columns in the table. 
>   This is why you can bind to a DataView or DataTable and see columns. 
>   However, when you bind to a List, there is no ITypedList that
>   can return the columns as properties.  It therefore falls back on
>   reflection and shows the physical properties of the DataRow class.

Comment: Thanks it works. For it I want to give you +1 but my rep points is less than 15 so I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var results = from myRow in ds.Table[0].Rows 
              where myRow.Field<int>("productID") == 23
              select myRow;
```

This should give you the rows you are looking for.